# Wordpress Gravatar and User Profiles

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, gravatar

I'm creating a wp template for a blog with many posts & authors (with gravatars and many comments). This blog is now hosted on wordpress.com so the users have custom avatars and logins.

The question:

I want to move the blog to a dedicated hosting, but how can I keep the gravatars and the logins so the users can login, comment and use their avatars on a self hosted wordpress instalation?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant that the blog is hosted on wordpress.com, not .org

Comment: Look into migration here http://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-a-blog/

Comment: Gravatar is external, just create backup and import database & configure on the dedicated server

Comment: The problem isn't the migration.

I want to let the users to use their wordpress account to log in, comment and write posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials on moving a blog from wordpress.com to a self hosted account.  Subscribers can be retained using JetPack, it also helps you keep a number of other wordpress.com features.

During the import you are given an option of what to do with authors, including using the user from the wordpress.com site.

Gravatars are not a problem, they are tied to the author's wordpress.com account using their email and will continue to work on your self hosted site.

To use JetPack you must retain your wordpress.com account.